# How to display a .rtf file into a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created a T&C for my app in `TextMate`. Then pasted it to a `.rtf` file created by `XCode`.

The content of the file is shown but I can see back-slashes when there are line breaks. What am I missing that this is happening?

```
NSError *e = Nil;
    NSString * tc = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"termsAndConditions" ofType:@"rtf"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@",e);
    tvView.text = tc;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.rtf file always contains Tags with itself for formating text color alignment and other properties, Try using a .txt file instead.

In TextEdit> Create a .txt file>Copy the contents from .rtf to .txt and use it.

You can use the same code by just renaming the file type.

```
NSError *e = Nil;
    NSString * tc = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"termsAndConditions" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@",e);
    tvView.text = tc;
```

Comment: Better yet, save it straight out of TextMate to txt

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question though, it makes it simpler, but what if you actually want formatted text displayed and loaded from an RTF?

Comment: Here's an attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970701/removing-fixed-text-width-from-an-rtf-file-loaded-into-uitextview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just replace the backslashes with blank ?

Such as

```
 tc = [tc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];
```