# Removing fixed text width from an RTF file loaded into UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, rtf

In my app I load the contents of an RTF file into a `UITextView` using this code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension] withExtension:[fileName pathExtension]];
NSError *error;
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:url 
                                                                           options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType}  
                                                                           documentAttributes:nil  
                                                                           error:&error];

[textView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

The problem I am having is that the width of the `UITextView` is greater than the text with of the rtf file. I want the text to fill the whole with of my `UITextView`.
You can see the problem below in the screenshot.

Is there a way to make this this happen?
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: That's a good looking app. Try setting the `backgroundColor` of the text view to something other than `clearColor` and see if it's the content that resizes or the text view.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the screenshot. What could be done with the rtf files is to remove the text borders  but the problem here is that the rtf's are managed by others and always have the text frames in them so it would be good if that could be done by code.